# WordPress Raw SQL Query Into WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently making a plug-in and need some help regarding a subject. I want to use all the the_loop goodness but need a raw sql query.

```
/**
 * Get all the posts neccessarry
 * return array<WP_Post> returns an array of all constructed WP_Posts
 */
public static function get_posts($o){
    global $wpdb;
    $posts = array();

    $tax= $o['tax'];

    $q=$wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
            WHERE meta_key='/$p/_faq_prio' 
            GROUP BY post_id
            ) AS pm 
         ON ( p.ID = pm.post_ID ),
         {$wpdb->term_relationships} t 

         WHERE p.post_type='faq' AND t.object_id = p.ID AND t.term_taxonomy_id = '{$tax}'
         ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC, ISNULL(pm.meta_key)", OBJECT_K);

    foreach ($q as $p) {
        array_push($posts, get_post($p) );  
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Does the get_post constructs a WP_Post object based on the data it
   receives, or does it extract the post_id parameters and queries the
   database yet again? I couldn't find this behavior from the
   reference guides.
2. How can I initilize a WP_Query object based on all the Posts object (should I manually set all parameters like postcount, etc or is there a better way?

Comment: first of all fix your code. since you have: `foreach ($q as $p)` you should use `$p` later when `get_post($p)`  but not **get_post($q)**

Comment: Fixed the code, do you perhaps know the answer to the second or the first question ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts